# How to send a message from a rails controller to a node server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to update the node server when I create a new model. I need something like a publish/subscribe pattern, where the subscriber is the node.js server and the publisher is the rails controller. Is there some way to achieve this?

*** * * * * EDIT * * * * ***

Thanks for to everyone that answered, I solved the problem using redis.

On Gemfile:

```
...
require 'redis'
...
```

Run **bundle install**

On config/initializers/redis.rb:

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port=> 6379)
```

On MyModel.rb:

```
...
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create {|my_model| my_model.message 'create' }
  after_update {|my_model| my_model.message 'update' }
  after_destroy {|my_model| my_model.message 'destroy' }

  def message action
    msg = { 'type': action, 'my_model': self }
    $redis.publish 'rt-change', msg.to_json
  end
end
...
```

On package.json:

```
...
"dependencies" : {
  ...
  "redis": "0.7.3"
},
...
```

Run **npm install**

On node.js:

```
var redis = require('redis').createClient();

redis.subscribe('rt-change');

redis.on('message', function(channel, message){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Redis, any MQ, or a simple HTTP request. I feel this question is just too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Basing on my experience, there are some solutions here:

1. Assume 2 nodes are sharing a storage/database, this is easy, right?
2. Assume the event is not important & there is 1 subscriber only

   - We create an internal api for node.js server which can receive the update events from rails controller
   - For every event from Rails, we assign it to a webhook controller to call above node.js api

[image]

`Pros`: Easy to implement

`Cons`: this event may be lost, if there is any problem while calling

For this, we may implement a retriable strategy, but it is complex since we will be confusing if there are so many failure, which will be retried or cancelled.

3. Assume event is important or there are so many subscriber: (This is my thought, I haven't implemented yet)

   - Whenever rails has event and want to multicast it to subscribers, we push this event to a message queue
   - All subscribers will pull above message from message queue and run updating.

   [AWS SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html) support us to do that, in case we are familiar to AWS, but so many alternatives outside.

`Pros`: Easy to publish to multiple subscribers

`Cons`: Time-consuming to implement

For all of these solutions, the `security` is crucial and must be considered, subscribers may receive the event from strangers? Yup, set the security up when making a solution as well

Answer (score 2):

A few steps to help you achieve this:

1. Create a message queue. You could use [Amazon SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/)
2. Create a controller in your Rails app that will broadcast a message to the message queue whenever an instance of the model is created. To broadcast the message in your Rails app, you could use a gem like [shoryuken](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken).
3. Create a worker process in your Node server that subscribes to events from the message queue. You can use the [aws-sdk](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) module for node.
4. When the worker process receives a message, it should parse it and act on it based on your business logic.